# Change "Manage_Stock" via REST API on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, manage-stock

Using Magento 2, I'm trying to change Manage Stock attribute via rest API however does not seem to work via both the stockItems endpoint or the product one. Updating quantity seems to work fine.

Tried like below initially:

```
    $url = "https://www.magestore.com/rest/all/V1/products/" . $sku;
    $post_data = array(
        'product' =>
        array(
            'sku' => $sku,
            'extension_attributes' => 
                array(
                    "stock_item" => array( 
                        "qty" => $qty,
                        "is_in_stock" => $is_in_stock,
                        "manage_stock" => true
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Then tried like this for the stockItems endpoint:

```
    $url = "https://www.magestores.com/rest/V1/products/" . $sku . "/stockItems/1";
    $post_data = array(
        "stock_item" => array( 
                "qty" => $qty,
                "is_in_stock" => $is_in_stock,
                "manage_stock" => true
            )
        );
```

However neither seem to change manage stock to true for me, is this possible to achieve with Rest API?

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry figured it out already, I think both were trying however `use_config_manage_stock` was still set to true. Changing post data to include this being set to false did the trick:

```
    $post_data = array(
        "stock_item" => array( 
                "qty" => $qty,
                "is_in_stock" => $is_in_stock,
                "use_config_manage_stock" => false,
                "manage_stock" => true
            )
        );
```